# How would I run the following command in windows?

Tags: windows, apache

How would I run the following command in Windows:

```
$ sudo ./configure
```

I want to run this Linux command using Windows command prompt. Actually, I am in the process of installing Apache thrift on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use the [binary release](http://thrift.apache.org/download). But if you really want to build from sources, you should read the documentation: http://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/windows